# Get Google Place Details Without Map

Tags: google-places-api

I have a reference to a Google Place, and use the Javascript API to get the place details.

It works fine as long as there is a map on the page.

But if there is no map - I only want the place's details - it breaks because the variable map is not defined.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) specifies:

"Place Details are requested with a call to the service's getDetails() method."

```js
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);
```

If I leave out the map variable, I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

I can make a server-side request, but there is a limit to the number of times you can do that.

Is there a way in Javascript to get just the place details without a map?

Comment: You can have the map on the page but don't give height and width to map_canvas. This way map will not be visible and search will work.

Answer (score 14):

After working with this for a bit, the solution I came up with was to create a new map object without appending it to the document. The API seems to be fine with this.

```js
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
```

Then make your request, same as before with the dummy map obj.

```js
this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
this.googlePlaces.getDetails(request, callback);
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this is allowed via terms? According to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies) page **"If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data"**  But why do they force you to specify an html elemnt?